# Uploadify and Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, upload, uploadify

I have a problem with uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) and Codeigniter framework (http://codeigniter.com).

Please check the Controller section :

```
function uploadFile()
    {
    require_once('class.upload.php');
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
         $uc = $this->session->userdata('username');
         //$_REQUEST['folder'] = "/pro/user/Dileepmt/pages/".$_REQUEST['folder']."/images/background";
         $_REQUEST['folder'] = $uc."/pro/user/".$uc."/pages".$_REQUEST['folder']."/images/background";
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .$_REQUEST['folder']. '/';
        $pic_temp = random_string('alnum',10);

        $handle = new Upload($_FILES['Filedata']);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_src_name_body      = $pic_temp; // hard name
                $handle->file_overwrite          = true;
                $handle->file_auto_rename        = false;
                $handle->image_resize            = true;
                $handle->image_ratio_y           = true;
                $handle->image_x                 = ($handle->image_src_x < 400)?$handle->image_src_x:400;
                $handle->file_max_size           = '819200'; // max size
                $handle->Process($targetPath);
                $handle->clean(); 
                if ($handle->processed)
                    $json = array("result"      => 1, 
                                  "file"        => $_REQUEST['folder'].'/'.$handle->file_dst_name.'?'.time(),
                                  "imagewidth"  => $handle->image_dst_x,
                                  "imageheight" => $handle->image_dst_y
                                 );
                else
                    $json = array("result" => 0);

                $encoded = json_encode($json);
                echo $encoded;
                unset($encoded);    
            } 
            else { 
                $json = array("result" => 0);
                $encoded = json_encode($json);
                echo $encoded;
                unset($encoded);
            }
}


    }
```

Uploadify have so many problems but here I fail to retrieve the session data using Codeigniter session library.

```
$uc = $this->session->userdata('username');

 $_REQUEST['folder'] = $uc."/pro/user/pages".$_REQUEST['folder']."/images/background";
```

assume that username = >'myuser' and 'folder' = >'myfolder'

so `$_REQUEST['folder']` will be `myuser/pro/user/pages/myfolder/images/background`

But the result is `/pro/user/pages/myfolder/images/background`

I checked there is no problem with Codeigniter session, I can set or retrieve data by using session library.

Answer (score 0):

Uploadify uses Flash. Flash is seperated from your Browser and does not send any session id or cookie. You can use uploadifies 'scriptData' attribute to send a session id or something. I generate an upload id in the html form and send it to uploadify. After the formular is submited I collect the files from the upload directory and connect them to the session.

Comment: i want to set the `FOLDER` option,it depends the session data.i think that it is very easy to alter `scriptData`.The Folder Path is like `/host/username/pages/images/background/file.ext`